# Applying templates to lion shaman Wildshape

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wild-shape, archetype

I have a level 11 Lion Shaman druid. I like to wildshape into lion forms for obvious reasons... he’s into lions.

So for lion shamans, my level 11 guy can shape into lions like a level 13 druid. I believe that kind of maxes out with huge animals with Beast Shape III.

Is there a way I can apply different templates to this lion, like giant for instance, to maximize my wildshape capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymorph spells, and abilities like wild shape that are based on them, are specifically barred from turning into templated versions of creatures. There are feats and such that supply specific exceptions, such as Planar Wild Shape, but none of those seem to allow the giant template.

There is an argument that *beast shape III*, for example, allows you to transform into a “Huge animal,” so that allows you to change into a lion except it is Huge. This is an extremely dubious reading of the rules in my mind, but web searches on this topic reveal a lot of people pushing it. This is functionally equivalent to applying the giant template, and while I find it a dubious interpretation of what the rules actually allow, as a GM I doubt I’d have any problem allowing it.

Comment: @FrancisJohn I misspoke when I suggested magical beasts—while *beast shape III* can do those, druid wild shape cannot.